# zip and unzip file c++

Tags: c++, linux, zip, unzip

I want to write code that zips a folder to a .zip file, or unzips a .zip file into a folder. I believe I need some library that supports it, am I right? If so, is there a specific library I should use? I want to write the code in C++ on a Linux machine (Ubuntu).
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, you will need a library.  The C++ language does not provide zip and unzip operations as programming constructs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend the [LZMA/7 Zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/) library. It supports a broad variety of compression formats and is usable for almost any kind of (OS) environment. The library API is in C and you can just pick what you need for your purpose (just decompression, compression or both) easily. It's also coming with an open source license that makes it easy to use in any kind of project (commercial or OS).

We're using this library in a number of embedded projects successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and I installed it on my machine, I want to write some code, is there an online reference, or online manual to know what to include, and the functions we can use?

Comment: @aizen92 As far as I remeber the README file(s) was/were helpful to figure out what you need.

Comment: Does liblzma supports decompressing a password protected zip file (compressed with zip utility)?

Answer (score 11):

If you want a higher-level way of doing this, you can call the `zip` and `unzip` commands directly from C++ using `system()` (or other process-starting mechanism). These utilities are available by default in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/), it's in C but is heavily tested, used for years, and it's portable almost on every platform that you can imagine.

Comment: zlib provides access to the compressed stream, but not the `.zip` file format, right?

Comment: @GregHewgill -- You are correct.

Comment: @GregHewgill http://www.zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq11 , so basically no but a solution is distributed with the source code itself, in the end you got everything you need.

Comment: You can try the contrib of zlib [minizip](https://github.com/madler/zlib/tree/master/contrib/minizip)

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [Rich Geldreich's miniz](https://code.google.com/p/miniz/).

Comment: I love it. Worked for me at the first try.

Answer (score 4):

Try [libzip](http://www.nih.at/libzip/).  I haven't used it, but it looks like it presents an API very similar to the stdio API for accessing compressed files within ZIP archives.

Answer (score -2):

It's not terribly hard to write your own unzip logic (using zlib for decompression).  (I''ve done this.)  Writing zip would be a bit more difficult but doable.

The zip spec is online [here](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

Comment: I prefer not to write from scratch at this point, as I'm going to take a course in the Fall about compression and their algorithms, so I'd rather read it, than implementing it, to get heads up about what I will be getting, but thanks for the spec, I'll make sure to read it

Comment: @aizen92 -- Ah, but writing something like that from scratch is an enormous amount of fun.  Even more fun than Angry Birds.

Comment: @HotLicks Hmmm, quite questionable point of view, if you just need s.th. supplementary in a project and get it done with minimal possible effort ...