# C++ unzip using IShellDispatch fails

Tags: c++, winapi, zip, unzip, compression

So I have a very simple job to do: **decompress a zip file**. Thought I'd find a simple solution withing 5 seconds online but I'm still struggling.

I've obviously read these posts:

- [Simple way to unzip a .zip file using zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10440113/1798187)
- [Simplest way to unpack ZIP from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18817056/1798187)

But the answers suggest to make use of `zlib` and `libzip` or `miniz`.
I'm sure these approaches works just fine. However it seems that it is not straightforward trying to apply this approach in existing VS2013 solution.

Then I came across this simple solution, [ref1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/280650/Zip-Unzip-using-Windows-Shell), [ref2](https://vcpptips.wordpress.com/tag/ishelldispatch/), that make use of [IShellDispatch object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537707(v=vs.85).aspx)

I rushed to implement it:

```
bool DecompressZIP(_In_ const wpath& pathFile, _In_ const wpath& pathDstDir)
{
    BSTR source = _bstr_t(pathFile.string().c_str());
    BSTR dest = _bstr_t(pathDstDir.string().c_str());

    HRESULT hResult = S_FALSE;
    IShellDispatch *pIShellDispatch = NULL;
    Folder *pToFolder = NULL;
    VARIANT variantDir, variantFile, variantOpt;

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    hResult = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Shell, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IShellDispatch, (void **)&pIShellDispatch);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hResult) && NULL != pIShellDispatch)
    {
        VariantInit(&variantDir);
        variantDir.vt = VT_BSTR;
        variantDir.bstrVal = dest;
        hResult = pIShellDispatch->NameSpace(variantDir, &pToFolder);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hResult) && NULL != pToFolder)
        {
            Folder *pFromFolder = NULL;
            VariantInit(&variantFile);
            variantFile.vt = VT_BSTR;
            variantFile.bstrVal = source;
            hResult = pIShellDispatch->NameSpace(variantFile, &pFromFolder);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hResult) && NULL != pFromFolder)
            {
                FolderItems *fi = NULL;
                pFromFolder->Items(&fi);

                VariantInit(&variantOpt);
                variantOpt.vt = VT_I4;
                variantOpt.lVal = FOF_NO_UI;

                VARIANT newV;
                VariantInit(&newV);
                newV.vt = VT_DISPATCH;
                newV.pdispVal = fi;
                hResult = pToFolder->CopyHere(newV, variantOpt);
                Sleep(1000);
                pFromFolder->Release();
                pToFolder->Release();
            }
        }
        pIShellDispatch->Release();
    }

    CoUninitialize();

    return true;
}
```

**BUT IT DOES NOT WORK !**

line:
`hResult = pIShellDispatch->NameSpace(variantFile, &pFromFolder);`
always result in `pFromFolder == NULL`

- `hResult` is `S_FALSE`
- `SUCCEEDED(hResult)` is true
- `GetLastError` is 0

### Question

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could start by telling us the `HRESULT` returned from the function that tosses a NULL pointer back at you. Are you claiming `SUCCEEDED(hResult)` is *true*, but `pFromFolder` is NULL ? An `else` condition with some detailed debug messaging may prove a worthwhile addition. If I had to *guess* it would be the `source` and `dest` BSTR values you're creating are from temporary `bstr_t` objects that are long-gone before you actually *use* their "inner-child".. I.e. you have a nice pair of dangling pointers there.

Comment: This is a risky way to do it. Expect failures on machines with broken shell associations. Throw away this code and use a real zip library.

Comment: Zip support in Explorer is very limited anyway. E.g. no unicode support, no support for secure encryption methods, no support for large (> 4GB) archives.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool CUnZip::Unzip2Folder(BSTR lpZipFile, BSTR lpFolder)
{
IShellDispatch *pISD;
Folder  *pZippedFile = 0L;
Folder  *pDestination = 0L;

long FilesCount = 0;
IDispatch* pItem = 0L;
FolderItems *pFilesInside = 0L;

VARIANT Options, OutFolder, InZipFile, Item;
CoInitialize(NULL);
__try{
    if (CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Shell, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellDispatch, (void **)&pISD) != S_OK)
        return 1;

    InZipFile.vt = VT_BSTR;
    InZipFile.bstrVal = lpZipFile;
    pISD->NameSpace(InZipFile, &pZippedFile);
    if (!pZippedFile)
    {
        pISD->Release();
        return 1;
    }

    OutFolder.vt = VT_BSTR;
    OutFolder.bstrVal = lpFolder;
    pISD->NameSpace(OutFolder, &pDestination);
    if (!pDestination)
    {
        pZippedFile->Release();
        pISD->Release();
        return 1;
    }

    pZippedFile->Items(&pFilesInside);
    if (!pFilesInside)
    {
        pDestination->Release();
        pZippedFile->Release();
        pISD->Release();
        return 1;
    }

    pFilesInside->get_Count(&FilesCount);
    if (FilesCount < 1)
    {
        pFilesInside->Release();
        pDestination->Release();
        pZippedFile->Release();
        pISD->Release();
        return 0;
    }

    pFilesInside->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch, (void**)&pItem);

    Item.vt = VT_DISPATCH;
    Item.pdispVal = pItem;

    Options.vt = VT_I4;
    Options.lVal = 1024 | 512 | 16 | 4;//http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787866(VS.85).aspx

    bool retval = pDestination->CopyHere(Item, Options) == S_OK;

    pItem->Release(); pItem = 0L;
    pFilesInside->Release(); pFilesInside = 0L;
    pDestination->Release(); pDestination = 0L;
    pZippedFile->Release(); pZippedFile = 0L;
    pISD->Release(); pISD = 0L;

    return retval;

}
__finally
{
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

}

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/45668d18-2840-4887-87e1-4085201f4103/visual-c-to-unzip-a-zip-file-to-a-specific-directory?forum=vclanguage

In the main, you call:

```
CUnZip * Z = new CUnZip();
        BSTR bstrFile = strFileName.AllocSysString();
        BSTR bstrPath = m_strPathName.AllocSysString();
        Z->Unzip2Folder(bstrFile, bstrPath);
        delete Z;
        Z = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try stepping through the code in a debugger? You have several bugs, and quite a few things that aren't bugs yet, but have lots of potential...

First, as WhozCraig said - you have two dangling pointers there, the two `BSTR`s. (In fact, if you manage to have the first first `NameSpace` call succeed, you'll see that the second `BSTR` changes to some GUID. Obviously the second call fails when it takes that argument.)

Second, you're using `wpath` instead of `wstring` or something like that. `wpath` puts forward slashes between the path components. But a lot of Windows code doesn't work with forward slashes, only backslashes. [`LoadLibrary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) is one example. Practically everything in the Shell is another (see the screenshot at the bottom of [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/181774/why-windows-uses-backslashes-and-everything-else-uses-forward-slashes/), for example).

Changing the `wpath`s to `wstring`s and the `BSTR`s to `_bstr_t`s is enough to make the code work.

---

Of course you should also get rid of the `VARIANT` is favour of `_variant_t`s, when you really need them, and use `_com_ptr_t`s instead of naked pointers, and preferably use `#import` for that.

That way the `NameSpace()` method takes a `_variant_t` instead of a `VARIANT`, and `_variant_t` has an implicit constructor from `_bstr_t`, so you can directly pass the `_bstr_t` to the function, without fiddling around with `VARIANT`s **or** `_variant_t`s.

Answer (score 0):

I meet same problem, when I use absolute path and the path separated symbol is '\', the problem is slove